# Setting PWA Service Worker File

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have a blog and I want to create a PWA version of it. I already created the manifest but I am a bit confused about the service worker settings. I have already created a service worker file but I am not sure if it will work fine. I used the guides on the Workbox website. I want my PWA to be capable of pre-cache, first network, cache the images/js/css/fonts etc., offline analytics, background, and periodic sync. Is my code ok for these features?

Here is my service worker code:

```
// Yapi Tasarim Akademisi Service Worker
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.setConfig({
debug: true,
});

import {
  pageCache,
  imageCache,
  staticResourceCache,
  googleFontsCache,
  offlineFallback,
} from 'workbox-recipes';

pageCache();

googleFontsCache();

staticResourceCache();

imageCache();

offlineFallback();



// Background sync


import {BackgroundSyncPlugin} from 'workbox-background-sync';
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {NetworkOnly} from 'workbox-strategies';

const bgSyncPlugin = new BackgroundSyncPlugin('myQueueName', {
  maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours (specified in minutes)
});

registerRoute(
  /\/api\/.*\/*.json/,
  new NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);




const statusPlugin = {
  fetchDidSucceed: ({response}) => {
    if (response.status >= 500) {
      // Throwing anything here will trigger fetchDidFail.
      throw new Error('Server error.');
    }
    // If it's not 5xx, use the response as-is.
    return response;
  },
};

// Add statusPlugin to the plugins array in your strategy.






// Offline Analytics

import * as googleAnalytics from 'workbox-google-analytics';

googleAnalytics.initialize();



// Pre-cache

import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching';

precacheAndRoute([
  {url: '/index.html', revision: '383676' },
  {url: '/styles/app.0c9a31.css', revision: null},
  {url: '/scripts/app.0d5770.js', revision: null},
  // ... other entries ...
]);
```